# API Name property in WSO2 Api Manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In the 2.6.0 version of the Api Manager from WSO2,  I was using custom sequence to log every flux with API Name, resources, applications, type of token etc... in Input and Output Seq

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="fn:concat('[V2][API][',$ctx:api.ut.application.name,'][',$ctx:API_NAME,'][',$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE,'][',$ctx:REST_SUB_REQUEST_PATH,'][',$ctx:api.ut.userId,'][',$ctx:EXECUTION_TIME_KAFKA,'][',$ctx:SYNAPSE_REST_API_VERSION,'][NOCOMMENT]')" name="LOG2PARSE"/>
</log>
```

Since 3.2.0, I am not able anymore to use the "$ctx:API_NAME" property.

Do you have any idea what is the right property to retrieve the API Name ? If I can, I do not want to use custom property to get the name.

Also, I can't find in the documentation which are the generics properties.
Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API Name you can use the following.

> $ctx:api.ut.api

Some of the other properties can be found here - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/APIMgtGatewayConstants.java#L24